# Closed form for the recurrence $c_0=-1,\ c_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{c_n+1}{2}}$ that computes $\cos(\pi/2^n)$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, recurrence-relations, closed-form

Let $c_n:=\cos(\pi/2^n)$ for $n\geq 0$. These values can be computed using the following recurrence (I can explain why if needed): $$c_0=-1,\ c_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{c_n+1}{2}}.$$

Is there a closed form for this recurrence? It there is, how can one find it? If there isn't, how can one prove it?

Comment: Sure there is:$c_n=\cos(\pi/2^n)$

Comment: Fair enough, @HagenvonEitzen

Comment: I believe it's not too hard to prove that the minimal polynomials of these values are of degree $2^{n-1}$, so no expression can be _too_ simple.

Comment: The same formula is satisfied by $C_n=\cos\frac\pi{5\cdot2^n}$ but with initial condition $$C_n=\sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt5}8}$$ A similar thing can be done with sine once one notes that $\cos^2+\sin^2=1$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In fact  you have, $$ \cos x= \sqrt{\frac{\cos 2x+1}{2}}~~~~~\text{for $0\le x\le \pi/2$}$$
>   Hence, $$ c_{n+1}=\cos \frac{\pi}{2^{n+1}}  = \sqrt{\frac{\cos \frac{\pi}{2^{n}}+1}{2}}= \sqrt{\frac{c_n+1}{2}}$$

**Below  is how you can find it.**

First see that for all $n>1$ we have $0\le c_n\le 1$ therefore there exists $a_n \in(0,\frac\pi2)$ such that

$$\color{blue}{c_n = \cos a_n!!!}$$

> Now what is the relation bwt $a_n$ and $a_{n+1}?$

we have, $$\cos a_{n+1} =c_{n+1}=\sqrt{\frac{c_n+1}{2}}= \sqrt{\frac{\cos a_n+1}{2}}  = \cos\frac{a_n}{2}$$

Basically we obtain $$a_{n+1} = \frac{a_n}{2}$$

which is a geometric sequence and therefore, $$a_n = \frac{a_1}{2^{n-1}}$$

Check that $$ \cos a_1 = 0\implies a_1 =\frac\pi2$$

This gives $$\color{red}{c_n = \cos\frac{\pi}{2^n}~~n\ge 1}$$

Comment: Your first formula is **not** correct in general, it would imply that $\cos(x) \ge 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: Yes I expressely restrict myself to interval $(0,\pi/2)$

Comment: The complete solution can be expressed as $c_n=\cos \bigg(\cos^{-1}(c_0)2^{-n} \bigg)$ for *any* $c_0$ (real or complex).

Comment: In addition, you suggest that your result is valid for $n\ge1$, whereas, it is actually valid for negative $n$ as well. Notice that I'm referring to a zero-based recurrence here. You can derive the solution from $c_n=2c_{n-1}^2-1$, where it is understood here that $n$ represents counting downward from $n=0$, even though $n$ is positive. The complete solutions is $c_n=\cos \bigg(\cos^{-1}(c_0)2^{n} \bigg)$.